# Problem in Cross compiling TinyCC with CodeSourcery

Tags: arm, cross-compilation, assembly

I am trying to cross compiling [homas Preud'homme's version of TinyCC](http://repo.or.cz/w/tinycc.git) by using following command

```
./configure --cc=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc --prefix=/home/shushant/tinycc/tc
```

and it shows following error message after running `make install`

```
make: Circular Makefile <- Makefile dependency dropped.
make -C lib native
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/shushant/tinycc/lib' arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -c alloca86_64.S -o x86_64/alloca86_64.o -I..  -Wall -g -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-pointer-sign -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-result -DTCC_TARGET_X86_64
alloca86_64.S: Assembler messages:
alloca86_64.S:7: Error: expression too complex -- `pop %rdx'
alloca86_64.S:11: Error: ARM register expected -- `mov %rdi,%rax'
alloca86_64.S:13: Error: ARM register expected -- `add $15,%rax'
alloca86_64.S:14: Error: ARM register expected -- `and $-16,%rax'
alloca86_64.S:15: Error: bad instruction `jz p3'
alloca86_64.S:28: Error: ARM register expected -- `sub %rax,%rsp'
alloca86_64.S:29: Error: ARM register expected -- `mov %rsp,%rax'
alloca86_64.S:35: Error: expression too complex -- `push %rdx'
alloca86_64.S:36: Error: bad instruction `ret'
alloca86_64.S:40: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `,'
make[1]: *** [x86_64/alloca86_64.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/shushant/tinycc/lib'
make: *** [libtcc1.a] Error 2
```

some how binaries is successfully generated but in wrong directory (at the root of `/home/shushant/tinycc`)  instead of `/home/shushant/tinycc/tc` and when I am trying to run on android emulator its show`file not found` of course generated binaries is not supported by device. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message shows that you want to compile code for your platform (x86/64) with the ARM compiler which does not work. The configure script has not guessed the correct target ("TCC_TARGET_X86_64" instead of the ARM target).

Probably, you need the `--cpu=armv7a` (or what you exactly have) option 
and/or the `--cross-prefix=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-` option. Before, run `make clean`.

Comment: thanks, jofel but now i am getting `cat: /VERSION: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target /Makefile, needed by Makefile.  Stop.`

Comment: The configure script seems to be broken a bit. I need to use `armv4l` otherwise I get a "Unsupported CPU warning". Additionally, I need to set `TCC_ARM_VERSION` in `config.h` manually (e.g. `#define TCC_ARM_VERSION 4`)